# Hot Restart: FutureBuilder using Firebase: "bad state: snapshot has neither data nor error"

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

While debugging, I found an issue which i have not found an answer which is might be from bad implementation.

Everytime I Hot Restart, while in the LoginView, It goes to a Case State with just one ConnectionState, which is done; no other I'm using so far so that might be an issue, here's a snippet of the code:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: AuthService.firebase().initialize(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          //ERROR HAPPENS HERE:
          case ConnectionState.done:
            final user = AuthService.firebase().currentUser;
            if (user != null) {
              if (user.isEmailVerified) {
                return const MenuPrincipal();
              } else {
                return const VerifyEmailView();
              }
            } else {
              return const LoginView();
            }

          default:
            return const Scaffold(
              body: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ],
              ),
            ); //const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Image of the error]

So what happens is everytime it builds, it goes directly to default, then it starts again but this time goes through to `final user = AuthService.firebase().currentUser;` and now it can decide.

What is the ideal case to solve an odd issue like this?

What i thought it would fix it is moving the user variable inside the switch but it gives errors and the Hot Restart checks the connectionState and fails to see the data and start an infinite Loop.

I've seen that probably moving the future from FutureBuilder to a initState, but I'm unsure if that could work since it is a statefulWidget parameter.